# Amazon Alexa "AskSdk.RequestEnvelopeUtils Error: Expecting request type of IntentRequest but got SessionEndedRequest."

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to play radio stations that the end-user can supply on my website.

This is what's supposed to happen:

**User:** open i. p. radio

**Echo:** Welcome to IP radio. You can ask me to play your favorite stations, or you can say help.

**User:** play generic radio station

**Echo:** Ok, playing 123.4: Generic Radio Station (then plays the station)

But this is what happens.

**User:** open i. p. radio

**Echo:** Welcome to IP radio. You can ask me to play your favorite stations, or you can say help.

**User:** play generic radio station

**Echo:** There was a problem with the requested skill's response.

And then this gets logged in the console:

```
2021-04-24T22:31:10.222Z    INFO    ~~~~ Error handled string: AskSdk.RequestEnvelopeUtils Error: Expecting request type of IntentRequest but got SessionEndedRequest.
```

The radio station is on port 8443.

Here is the code that runs:

```js
const PlayStationIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'PlayRadio';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        function reallyHandle() {
            return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
                let response = await axios.get("https://msbc.one/api/stations", {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken}})
                if (response.data.length === 0) {
                    const speakOutput = "You have no stations added! You can add stations at, m s b c dot one. Login, and follow the instructions."
                    res(handlerInput.responseBuilder
                        .speak(speakOutput)
                        .getResponse());
                } else {
                    let station_url;
                    let station_title;
                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        console.log("~~~~ over here! " + response.data[i].command + "\n\n" + handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.station.value)
                        if (response.data[i].command === handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.station.value) {
                            station_url = response.data[i].url
                            station_title = response.data[i].title
                        }
                    }
                    if (!station_url) {
                        const speakOutput = "That station does not exist, please try again."
                        res(handlerInput.responseBuilder
                            .speak(speakOutput)
                            .reprompt(speakOutput)
                            .getResponse());
                    } else {
                        const speakOutput = "OK, playing " + station_title + "."
                        const builder = handlerInput.responseBuilder
                        builder.speak(speakOutput)
                        builder.addDirective({
                            type: "AudioPlayer.Play",
                            playBehavior: "ENQUEUE",
                            audioItem: {
                                stream: {
                                    url: station_url,
                                    token: handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.station.value,
                                    offsetInMilliseconds: 0,
                                }
                            },
                            metadata: {
                                title: station_title,
                                subtitle: "IP Radio",
                            }
                        })
                        res(builder.getResponse())
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        if (!handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken) {
            const speakOutput = "Welcome to IP radio. To use the full features of this skill, please link your account. I've sent a card to your Alexa app with more instructions."
            
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speakOutput)
                .withLinkAccountCard()
                .getResponse();
        } else {
            let okDoThis = await reallyHandle()
            return okDoThis;
        }
        
    }
};
```

Thank you and have a nice day.

**Edit:** I have gone through and tried removing the speakOutput, still not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem because I used the playBehavior `ENQUEUE` instead of `REPLACE_ALL`, because `ENQUEUE` expects a token because if it doesn't match the token from before, it doesn't work. `REPLACE_ALL` removes all running streams on the Echo device and plays that stream.

Have a nice day everyone!